# My laptop doesn't recognize USB 3.1 C external SSD's

Tags: ssd, usb-3

I'm on Windows 10 pro, and I’m attaching an NVMe SSD in an external enclosure using a USB Type C 3.1 to USB Type C 3.1 cable, and a [Samsung T5 Portable SSD - 1TB - USB 3.1 External SSD (MU-PA1T0B/AM)](https://www.samsung.com/us/computing/memory-storage/portable-solid-state-drives/portable-ssd-t5-1tb-mu-pa1t0b-am/) with the same cable type (tried multiple cables).

I installed the driver for thunderbolt and updated the firmware and when I plug in a USB 3.1 ssd external device I hear the device attached sound from windows but no drive shows up in my computer or disk manager. I tried several drives that work when connected to USB 3.0 type A ports.

Does anyone have any idea why this isn’t working?

[image]

Comment: USB 3.1 Gen 1 or USB 3.1 Gen 2.  I ask this question because USB 3.1 Gen 1 is USB 3.0. Based on the fact the older Gen 1 devices work my guess is the host doesn’t support Gen 2

Comment: @Ramhound The Cable is the Gen 2 reversible plug on both ends

Comment: ie type c connector

Comment: It being a Type C connector doesn’t guarantee it’s Gen 2.   The device is Gen 2, the cable and host must both support Gen 2, for the device to be recognized

Comment: @Ramhound It's a driver problem or software problem with my laptop not the external. The T5 is the best selling external on amazon and works for other people. I have two and neither works over usb c

Comment: Drive isn’t a thunderbolt drive.  I am confused why you would install unrelated drivers.  You have two other USB 3.1 Gen 2 storage devices?  If that’s the case then this SSD should work.  As I indicated both the host (which we know nothing about) and the cable must support Gen 2.  It being type C does not guarantee it’s Gen 2

Comment: @Ramhound The host controller is on the hard drive right? Both the hard drive and my laptop are gen 2. Please see the Microsoft driver that I photo'ed which appears in device manager on attaching the drive.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86223/discussion-between-ramhound-and-user5389726598465).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I installed the driver for Thunderbolt and updated the firmware and when I plug in a USB 3.1 SSD external device I hear the device attached sound from windows but no drive shows up in my computer or disk manager. I tried several drives that work when connected to USB 3.0 type A ports.

While your device does have a Thunderbolt 3 port, the firmware you installed, is not relevant to your issue.  The device you purchased is a USB 3.1 Gen 2 device, your laptop, [GT72S-6QD-DOMINATOR-G](https://www.msi.com/Laptop/support/GT72S-6QD-DOMINATOR-G**) only has a single USB 3.1 Gen 1 Type-C port.

> Does anyone have any idea why this isn’t working?

Based on the [Samsung T5 SSD](https://www.samsung.com/us/computing/memory-storage/portable-solid-state-drives/portable-ssd-t5-1tb-mu-pa1t0b-am/) documentation, both the host and the cable must support USB 3.1 Gen 2.  Your laptop does not support USB 3.1 Gen 2.  This is the reason the device cannot be mounted within Windows using the provided *Type C to Type C* cable..  **The simple solution is to use a *Type-C to USB A* cable, and utilize the drives backward compatible, with USB 3.1 Gen 1 (also known as USB 3.0).**

Comment: This answer assumes the drive is actually operational and isn't simply defective.

Comment: The support ticket from MSI concurred that I have a gen 1 despite being Thunderbolt 3 as you stated, however page 3 of the manual for T5 requirements state [*1. USB 3.1 Gen 2 (10 Gbps) or USB 3.1 Gen 1 (5 Gbps) Interface Support *](http://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/UM/201711/20171106202904315/Samsung_Portable_SSD_T5_User_Manual_v0.0_Rev01_English.pdf), so I'm still back to debugging.

Comment: USB 3.1 Gen 1 (USB 3.0) would be provided by using the *Type-C to Type A* cable.